# How can i hide specific value in php code?

Tags: php, printing

Hi i want to hide a field but i can't. I searched if value code but i can't find. I am not php coder. I need only this code.

```
<?php 
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $type = $field['s_type'];
        $label = $field['s_label'];
        $value = Attributes::newInstance()->getValue($item_id, $field['pk_i_id']);
        if ($type == 'checkbox') {
            if ($value == 'checked') $value = '<img src="http://www.tirnakicinde.com/oc-content/plugins/realestate_attributes/img/tick.png">';
            **else $value = '<img src="http://i.imm.io/RLMH.png">';**
        }
?>
        <tr>
            <td style='width: 150px;'><?php _e($label, PLUGIN_NAME); ?></td>
            <td style='width: 150px;'><?php _e($value, PLUGIN_NAME); ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

`<img src="http://i.imm.io/RLMH.png">` is are my "NO" tick. I want to hide when selected NO *(this is my nO tick value `<img src="http://i.imm.io/RLMH.png">` tick then it don't display. I used image code for no tick.

How can i hide?

Comment: I think what you are trying accomplish is to toggle between "ticked" and "unticked" images, toggling the checkbox too. You need to use javascipt for this, PHP is nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is he's just trying to get rid of the picture which is loaded when the checkbox is "unchecked" (the "no tick" as he calls it).
If so, try removing *else* branch for condition *if ($value == 'checked')*

+1 EXP for understanding the question

Comment: Flavio thanks for answer but I don't understand. Sorry but my English is not enough. Can you edit the above code and paste here please?

Comment: This is work. Very thanks. NO tick is removed but no tick's labels still showing. No ticks and no tick's labeld must be hide. When checked no, No tick's and it's labels must be hide but yes tick's must be show.